# Autocomplete predictions with new Places api

Tags: android, google-places-api, autocompletetextview, google-places-autocomplete

I'm trying to update my autocomplete adapter in order to use the new Google Places api for Android. Everything worked fine with the deprecated api but, after updating to the new one, I'm getting an odd exception. Here is my code:

```java
     private ArrayList<AutocompletePrediction> getAutocomplete(CharSequence constraint) {
            final ArrayList<AutocompletePrediction> resultList = new ArrayList<>();

            RectangularBounds bounds = RectangularBounds.newInstance(mBounds);
            FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest request = FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest.builder()
                    //.setLocationBias(bounds)
                    //.setLocationRestriction(bounds)
                    //.setCountry("es")
                    //.setTypeFilter(TypeFilter.ADDRESS)
                    .setSessionToken(mAutocompleteSessionToken)
                    .setQuery(constraint.toString())
                    .build();

            Task<FindAutocompletePredictionsResponse> autocompletePredictions = this.mPlacesClient.findAutocompletePredictions(request);
            try {
                Tasks.await(autocompletePredictions, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            }catch (ExecutionException | TimeoutException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }catch (InterruptedException ie){
                Log.d(TAG, ie.getLocalizedMessage());
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }

            if (autocompletePredictions.isSuccessful()) {
                FindAutocompletePredictionsResponse findAutocompletePredictionsResponse = autocompletePredictions.getResult();
                if (findAutocompletePredictionsResponse != null) {
                    resultList.addAll(findAutocompletePredictionsResponse.getAutocompletePredictions());
                }
            }

            return resultList;
        }
```

When the code reaches the Tasks.await line, throws an Exception like this:

```
2019-06-06 16:40:34.374 15915-16101/com.my.new.app D/PlaceAutocompleteAdaptr: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 7: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Hostname maps.googleapis.com not verified:
        certificate: sha1/um1YfTYENrO2PbPGj5v0Jra2BlQ=
        DN: CN=*.googleapis.com,O=Google LLC,L=Mountain View,ST=California,C=US
        subjectAltNames: [*.googleapis.com, *.clients6.google.ae, *.clients6.google.at, *.clients6.google.be, *.clients6.google.ca, *.clients6.google.ch, *.clients6.google.cl, *.clients6.google.co.id, *.clients6.google.co.il, *.clients6.google.co.in, *.clients6.google.co.jp, *.clients6.google.co.kr, *.clients6.google.co.nz, *.clients6.google.co.uk, *.clients6.google.co.ve, *.clients6.google.co.za, *.clients6.google.com, *.clients6.google.com.ar, *.clients6.google.com.au, *.clients6.google.com.br, *.clients6.google.com.co, *.clients6.google.com.eg, *.clients6.google.com.kw, *.clients6.google.com.mx, *.clients6.google.com.om, *.clients6.google.com.pe, *.clients6.google.com.ph, *.clients6.google.com.qa, *.clients6.google.com.sa, *.clients6.google.com.sg, *.clients6.google.com.tr, *.clients6.google.com.tw, *.clients6.google.com.ua, *.clients6.google.com.vn, *.clients6.google.cz, *.clients6.google.de, *.clients6.google.dk, *.clients6.google.es, *.clients6.google.fi, *.clients6.google.fr, *.clients6.google.ie, *.clients6.google.is, *.clients6.google.it, *.clients6.google.jp, *.clients6.google.nl, *.clients6.google.no, *.clients6.google.pl, *.clients6.google.pt, *.clients6.google.ro, *.clients6.google.ru, *.clients6.google.se, *.cloudendpointsapis.com, cloudendpointsapis.com, googleapis.com]
```

Any advice on this? I'm pretty sure that everything is ok in the cloud console: api key, restrictions, billing information, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Exception was provoked by a poor `HostnameVerifier` implementation used in other part of the code. The custom `HostnameVerifier` was setted by default this way:

```
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {

            @Override
            public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) {
                if(arg0.contains("mydomain.com") || arg0.contains("myotherdomain.com")) {
                    return true;
                }else {
                    return false;
                }
            }

        });
```

So, as you can see, this code returns false with googleapis.com, which in fact is the domain used by the new Google Places library for Android.

This is legacy code in a project I must update. **I really do not recommend overriding the default HostnameVerifier.**

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding custom `HostNameVerfier` to your `OkHttpClieknt`

```
okHttpClient.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
            @Override
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                return true;
            }
        });
```

If you are using `Retrofit`, set `OkHttpClient` as follows:

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
okHttpClient.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
                @Override
                public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                    return true;
                }
            });

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder() .client(okHttpClient).build();
```

Comment: The problem was somehow related with a HostnameVerifier. I have posted an answer.